# Start subprocess with environment variables

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I need to start a process where I pass some parameters to the sub-process in environment variables.

I know I can use `subprocess.run()` to do this in python > 3.5. How can I do it with python 2.7 ?

In python 2.7 I can modify the environment variables of the process that start the sub-process. The sub-process will inherit the environment variables. But I don’t want that. I want to set the environment variables only in the sub-process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `subprocess.Popen('env', env={'A':'5','B':'5'})`

Sample run:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('env', env={'A':'5','B':'5'})
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x102288950>
>>> A=5
B=5
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> If env is not None, it must be a mapping that defines the environment
> variables for the new process; these are used instead of inheriting
> the current process’ environment, which is the default behavior.

Python3 `subprocess.run()` is [using](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) the same `Popen` kwarg `env`:

> The full function signature is largely the same as that of the Popen
> constructor